# Node referencing: How do you display a node with all its references?

Tags: views, nodes

Ingredients:

- Drupal7 + References + Views module installed
- 2 content types: magazine issue + magazine articles (for each issue)
- Article c-type has a reference field: issue_no which displays the
  issue it belongs
- I made a Views to display me a plain list of issues only.

Requirements

1. When I click on the issue in the issue list I want to see all its references nodes(=articles) attached
2. I need to highlight the latest issue in the list by creating a separate page VIEW on the frontpage that contains articles of the latest view.

I would appreciate any help.

Here is a prinscreen on my content type > manage display

[image]

Comment: In the node reference field are you referring to both issues and articles?

Comment: No, I have only a reference field in the article content type referenceing the issue it belongs.

Comment: And where you say "I am currently see all articles and magazine issues mixed together." is this on a teaser or full body? Which content type are you viewing the issue or the article?

I have you enabled the reverse link option so the issues show on the article?

Comment: Well, I am seeing in the homepage a list of issues and articles teasers. I need a list of issues when I click on it to open a list of articles inside. While clicking on issue now I see its fields (I need to see the list of articles inside). I didn't know about reverse link option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There several ways (at least) to do it. The solution we've discussed here is relevant only for one node reference. I found no way to display multiple node references

- A. Using taxonomy. Create taxonomy terms: issue1, issue2 and display
  an articles under one of this
- B. Duplicate BackLinks View ( a preset    of Views )
- C. In issue custom type create a field for each article.    The type 
  of the field must pe node reference. (autosuggestions).After
  adding articles , the editor will create a new issue and type the
  article to be displayed in those article fields.
- D.Create A view and add a footer. In the footer add a new view (the
  articles).

Answer (score 0):

Install views and have it manage your home page, then add a content type filter so that it only shows issues on your home page. This will stop your home page being a mix of articles and issues.

Then, go to each content type and go to "manage display", in there you can specify the format, by default this is set to title (link). You also have an option for "full rendered node" which will display the whole referenced content inline.

Alternatively you could use views and create a block with the nid as a argument so it displays references content in a way you can choose fields to display etc

Comment: Hi Westie, I carrefully followed your instructions, but I cannot manage to find option for "full rendered node" on issue content-type manage display tab (admin/structure/types/manage/issue/display).

Comment: I would appreciate if you can get me out :). The paragraph 2 is essential to me.

Comment: On that page you have a "format" column with select elements, on the row for your node reference field you should have an option "rendered node". Once you save this and go back to that page a cog icon should appear in the far right of that row. Clicking on that allows you to choose a "view mode", you can select "Full content" / "Teaser" etc

Comment: Oh I found what you said but in the content-type: article, because the reference field is here. content-type:issue has no reference field. Should have?

Comment: I can display the articles to contain a full rendered issue node :). But I need up-side-down. An issue to display ALL articles.

Comment: Hi that is the "reverse link option" it will put the reference display on both the referred "from" and referred "to" nodes. If that is no go you might be best just adding the node reference field in the opposite way, for example add the reference field to issue and have that reference all the articles.

Comment: I did that but I can only fetch one article per issue:)